# Add model attribute to same model in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model called Company. The Company could be the child of a bigger company. So in the model Company should be a attribute "parent" that is also a Company.

I got this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="notification",
        null=True,
        blank=False,
    )
```

But django is always saying I need to create a Company class. Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Igor's answer works perfectly. You may further look at django-mptt package if you need hierarchical relationships.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'self' keyword to reference the same model.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="notification",
        null=True,
        blank=False,
    )
```